# Using redux persist to create shopping cart not returning state.cart in createSlice

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

i am trying to build a shopping cart using Redux/toolkit and persist-redux library.

first note: when iam not using redux-persist, everything works!

here i create a slice:

```
import { createSlice, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    cart: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log(state.cart, "ttt");
      const itemExists = state.cart.find(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemExists) {
        itemExists.qty++;
      } else {
        state.cart.push({ ...action.payload, qty: 1 });
      }
    },
    incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      item.qty++;
    },
    decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      if (item.qty === 1) {
        const index = state.cart.findIndex(
          (item) => item.id === action.payload
        );
        state.cart.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        item.qty--;
      }
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      const removeItem = state.cart.filter(
        (item) => item.id !== action.payload
      );
      state.cart = removeItem;
    },
  },
});


export const cartReducer = cartSlice.reducer;
export const {
  addToCart,
  incrementQuantity,
  decrementQuantity,
  removeFromCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;
```

and here is my store.js file:

```
//store.js

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import generalSlice from "./slices/generalSlice";
import { cartReducer } from "./slices/cartSlice";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, cartReducer);
// config the store
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    generaldata: generalSlice,
    cart: persistedReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

and here is my _app.js file:

```
import { store, persistor } from "../store/index";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
..
..
return(
<Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        ...
        </PersistGate>
</Provider>
)
```

i have two problems now:
the first one: when i click on addToCart button and dispatch addToCart action, i get this error:

```
TypeError: state.cart.find is not a function

 11 | addToCart: (state, action) => {
  12 |   console.log(state.cart, "ttt");
> 13 |   const itemExists = state.cart.find(
     |                                ^
  14 |     (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
  15 |   );
  16 |
```

the second one, in the cart.js page, i get this value of consloe.log(cart):

```
Object
cart
: 
_persist
: 
{version: -1, rehydrated: true}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
generaldata
: 
{sitedata: {…}}
_persist
: 
{version: -1, rehydrated: true}
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

this is my cart.js some code:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
..
..
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

console.log(cart, "fff");
```

any help?

Answer (score 0):

Better to use the initial state as [] directly instead of having

```
initialState: {
  cart: [],
},
```

Here is the updated slice code.

```
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const itemExists = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id);
      if (itemExists) {
        itemExists.qty++;
      } else {
        state.push({ ...action.payload, qty: 1 });
      }
    },
    incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      item.qty++;
    },
    decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      if (item.qty === 1) {
        const index = state.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload);
        state.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        item.qty--;
      }
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      const removeItem = state.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload);
      return removeItem;
    },
  },
});
```

Here the cart property can be accessed directly

Comment: i also tryed this. the same errors..